Late 90s/2000s movie where US soldiers in a winter enviroment sing "Working on the Railroad" and then get shot
Story Points:

The soldiers attack an enemy outpost that has a few civilian buildings. I can't remember the nationality of the enemy troops, but judging from the winter enviorment, I think they might be russians/russian insurgents/soviets
After the US troops take over the outpost, a dozen or so troops group together and sing "working on the railroad", whilst other troops watch over the prisoners. Afterwards, the soldiers singing are then shot by an enemy soldiers located in a nearby house on the second floor. The second floor room where the sniper is located is then promptly shot at by the US troops and perhaps even destroyed by grenades.


I'm fairly convinced this is actually a Band of Brothers episode (The Breaking Point) from 2001.

Easy Company remains in the Ardennes Forest preparing for an inevitable attack on German forces in the town of Foy. However, morale is low due to cold weather, constant shelling, poor leadership, and numerous casualties.

It's in a wintery setting and IIRC they sing "Been Working on the Railroad", a sniper picks them off and he's eventually bombed. See if this rings any bells:



